# Executing Linux commands from UI (Html Page)

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, centos, centos7

I am trying to learn, how can I execute the linux commands on a web page by taking the input from user.

Basically, I want a simple html page which will take few inputs from user and it will run few commands on the server.

I am confused as I did not find anything on the internet or youtube or maybe I am just not able to trigger the specific keywords.

For example : I want to create a directory of some name, so I want to give a name to it. So in that case, On html page I will post something like

`Name of Folder : ________`

and then when I give the name and hit submit button it should create a directory in my linux system.

From linux we just need to use 'mkdir "name"'

Suggest me if this could be done via python or anything else or simple way to achieve this.

I hope you understand my query. If you will give or post a simple example on how to achieve that. I will be grateful. I am kind of new to this. Thanks for your time :)

If you can post few article links or video examples that can also be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this tutorial](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/python-web-server-with-flask)  for building a Flask web page.

In the step 6, you'll see that every request is routed to a function like this

```python
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name):
    return render_template('page.html', name=name)
```

So you can use something like

```python
import os

@app.route('/mkdir/<dirname>')
def hello(name):
    ret = os.system("mkdir {}".format(dirname))
    return render_template('page.html', name=dirname)
```

in order to create a dir using mkdir in a linux host.

Keep into account that this method is not secure as does not check for the command to be valid nor malicious code to be injected. This is just a starting point for you to start learning.